# Type hint for attribute that might not exist

Tags: python, attributes, python-typing

How do I do a type hint for attribute that might not exist on the object in Python?
For example:

```py
class X:
    attr: int  # either int or doesn't exist - what do I put here?
```

Comment: could do `int | None = None`, but bear in mind everything that uses `X` will need to handle the `None`

Comment: Your question is not well defined. What exactly do you mean by _"might not exist"_? What should I expect to happen, when I use an instance of `X` and try to access its `attr` attribute? Do you mean, I would either get an integer or an `AttributeError`?

Comment: `attr: int` under `class X` indicates an instance attribute which is to be populated some time after instance creation. There's always a chance that it may not exist before the instance is populated with attributes, or if you delete the attribute. You need to frame the question in terms of *what you want the static analyser to emit if the attribute doesn't exist*, and *under what circumstance you want this warning emission to happen*.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg What I mean is that an instance of `X` could have the `attr` but might not.  So when you do `instance_of_x.attr` it might return an int or it might raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: In that case, as @dROOOze said, this is just the normal state of instance attributes in Python. The annotation should be `attr: int`. The _lack_ of an attribute is not a type. Assuming that _most_ of the time I should expect an instance of `X` to _have_ an `attr` attribute, I would say it should be annotated accordingly. If it is just one ephemeral, dynamically set attribute among many, and it was just as likely for it to be missing altogether, I would refrain from annotating it at all.

Answer (score -3):

Just use the `Optional` class that comes bundled with the `Typing` module.

[Here is it's documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional)

Here's how we can apply it to your example case:

```
from typing import Optional

class X:
    attr: Optional[int]
```

**Edit**: Since you need to just check if the variable is created and the attribute exists in the object, here is two ways you can do this:

Using [Locals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)/[Globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) built-in function from Python:

```
if variable_name in locals():
    print(f"Variable exists locally.")

if variable_name in globals():
    print(f"Variable exists globally.")
```

Or, the easiest way, just do a [Try/Exception](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch17s02.html):

```
try:
    x
    some_operation(x)
except NameError:
    some_fallback_operation(  )
```

I linked documentations from Python on Globals/Locals function, and a topic from O'Reily Cookbook that explains the Try/Exception method.

**Edit 2**: Added another [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to work on objects/classes that is in the same documentation link I sent from globals() - The *getattr()* method.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = "Whatever"


obj = MyClass()

# Try/Catch to try accessing a non-existing variable.
try:
    whatever = getattr(obj, "attribute")
    print(whatever)
except AttributeError:
    print("Error - There is no variable.")
```

I hope this helps you. :)

Comment: `Optional[int]` means that the attribute is an `int` or `None`. What I want is that `attr` is either an `int` or doesn't exist at all on that instance. An attribute not existing on an object is **different** to the attribute being `None`.

Comment: I see. I updated the question with two alternatives on how you can achieve this.

Comment: Judging from your edits, I am afraid you completely missed the point of the question. It is about how to statically _annotate the type_ of an attribute that may or may not be present on an object. The question is _not_ about how to check for its existence at runtime.

Comment: I did'nt understand it at all then.